# PyQt5 select text across multiple QTextEdit boxes

Tags: select, pyqt, pyqt5, qtextedit

I am trying to create something similar to this in PyQt5:
https://www.screencast.com/t/1FikGosKbS

I tried using a separate QTextEdit widget for each bullet point and overriding the enter key to go to the next textbox, but I don't know how to make multiple QTextEdit widgets selectable (and able to copy paste) like in the example.

How can I allow the user to drag to select text across multiple QTextEdit boxes? Or is there a better approach to this?

Comment: This application can be editted by users?It seems that it is a type of read-only documents,because the user only click the nodes.It seems that the TO-DO datas themselves are imported and rendered from somewhere.

Comment: @user9402680 Yes, it is Workflowy, a note taking app. 
https://workflowy.com/demo/embed/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know this application is made from Qt or not,but I have an idea.
Parhaps you might have made the most part of this application... I can't know them from your question.I write my opinion on the premise that you don't know QText handling at all.

`QTextEdit`,`QTextDocument`,`QTextCursor` are used fully.

1.To understand [block](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/richtext-structure.html).

2.To use `QTextBlockUserData`(If you want.)

3.To use `QGraphicsItem` as nodes.

4.To go other page,we add a new `QTextEdit` on `QStackedWidget` or replace the `QTextDocument` of `QTextEdit`.

5.To make sub-nodes block,you can coordinate the indentation of blocks.

`QTextBlock` is a read-only data in a document.

You make `QTextBlockUserData` and set it to the block.

If you select multiple blocks you want to drag & drop , you use `QTextCursor` and `movePosition` methods with sequence.

The nodes of this application can not be `QTextListFormat`,because we cannot handle mouse click on the style.But you can insert empty-style `QTextListFormat`.

The truth of the nodes may be `QGraphicsItem`.

You can allocate it each the start position of blocks and the item can also have the block data.

It will difficult to take care of the connection between the nodes and the blocks.
In advance, you must set `QGraphicsView` & `QGraphicsScene`.

I insert many data on the container.

Which should we control with nodes or block?

**My trial**.

**1.Nodes & Text**
[image]

**2.To the other page**
[image]

**3.Sub nodes & blocks**
[image]

**4.close sub nodes & blocks**
[image]

My trial is incomplete,but it will be completed with endurance.
Logically,I think I can go step until the good point with these combinations.
But it will be diffcult...

These nodes are made from QGraphicsItem and allocated each Blocks.
You must calculate the position and recalculate during editing.

The mouse cursor image is deleted on these images.
It is outrange of screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I made the similar thing by reading and following [this book](https://www.amazon.co.jp/World-Qt-English-Harunori-Fujimoto/dp/B0CPYQTG6F/ref=sr_1_56?__mk_ja_JP=%E3%82%AB%E3%82%BF%E3%82%AB%E3%83%8A&crid=1LKMH56U8PDY0&keywords=Qt&qid=1707214237&sprefix=qt%2Caps%2C170&sr=8-56).

The best approach is to reimplement 'QAbstractTextDocumentLayout'.

This makes us possible to use unvisible `QTextBlock`.

This answer is too long to write here. sorry.